# Sum and convert time with t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I'm trying to sum total time needed to complete all cases during one session. Time per case is stored in [time] column, in seconds. How to sum it and convert to the hh:mm:ss format?

My code looks like that:

```
[sessionno] as session_no
,count ([id]) as No_Items
,(convert (varchar, dateadd (ms, (sum([time])) * 1000, 0), 108)) as total_work_time
```

The result should look like:

```
session_no | No_items | total_work_time
112138          8         00:35:12
112583          0         00:00:00
212558          1         00:00:17
```

Instead of that I receive:

```
session_no | No_items | total_work_time
112138          8         1622
112583          0         null
212558          1         324
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `[time]` column?

Comment: `dateadd(ss, sum(time), cast('00:00:00' as time))`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please post ddl for your table(s) and some sample data as insert statements? But I question about summing time. What is a 9:13am plus 3:42pm supposed to be? Adding times of day makes no logical sense. I think you are confusing time of day with the duration of a task.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `select (convert (varchar, dateadd (ms, (1234) * 1000, 0), 108))` produces `00:20:34`. Check your assumptions.

Comment: @TabAlleman it is int

Comment: @awelpu then I agree with Jeroen, your issue is not reproducible.   Provide a script that fully reproduces the issue, or your question will likely be closed.

Comment: @TabAlleman, actually answer provided by Radim Bača helped me with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Few corrections of your SQL

```
 SELECT [sessionno] as session_no,
        count ([id]) as No_Items,
        dateadd (ss, sum([time]), cast('00:00:00' as time)) as total_work_time
 FROM your_table
 GROUP BY [sessionno]
```

However, be aware that the time datatype may [overflow](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2d73285ba779ed039b4ea4e03183c576).